# why does the memory my program uses keep growing as it runs?

Tags: c++, memory, 2d, sdl, game-engine

From first searching about this I found some sources saying i probably have a memory leak. But when i searched into detail about what a memory leak is, it said i happens when i use "new" and dont use "delete" But i didnt use new even once in my whole program so im assuming that means the problem is something else. I dont have any growing arrays or anything else i can think of that would cause this. After the initialization of the program i would imagine it would not change after that, but i grows, and quite quickly might i add.

the program is very large so i dont think pasting it all here would be a good idea. perhaps just some general ideas of things that could cause this that could help me know where to look.

just to give an idea, the application is a 2d side scroller, like super mario world

Comment: Even you _you_ don't use `new` directly doesn't mean some other code you use doesn't. If you use e.g. `std::vector` it will increase (and allocate memory) as you add to it.

Comment: Also, the operating system can keep memory reserved for a process even after the process releases it, to save time if the process needs to allocate memory again. This may be mistaken for a memory leak.

Comment: And lastly, if you're on Linux or Mac OSX you can use a tool called [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to help find memory leaks. Visual Studio has something similar built into the CRT if you debug your application.

Comment: Depending on what environment you work in there are probably tools that would allow you to pinpoint the problem. E.g. on debian linux I used `-dbg` versions of external libraries, compiled mine with symbols and other neede stuff and used `valgrind`. It can even show which `new` did not get `delete` in your own code. Or show which call had allocated memory that did not get deallocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `SDL`, I suspect the allocations are coming from `SDL` in calls like `IMG_Load` or `SDL_LoadWave`. As a rule of thumb, when an API gives you a pointer, it means that you have to ask the API to free it as well.

Taking a [`SDL_Surface`](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_Surface) for example, calling `IMG_Load` (or any other API functions to allocate an image) will allocate memory. You will need to manually call `SDL_FreeSurface` on each of your `SDL_Surface` to free the memory when you're done with them.

It's the same thing with every other resource in `SDL`.

Comment: hmm, Yes but im pretty sure I AM using Free_Surface and the other clean up functions for each resource when im done with them. after the initialization of the program, the amount of resources i declare or use stays the same. Yet the programs memory use increases like 300kbs / sec. The main thing happening is the program is "apply_surface(" before each screen refresh? am I supposed to free the old surface first before i apply the updated one perhaps?

Comment: I guess you followed a tutorial on Lazy Foo? If your apply surface just calls `SDL_BlitSurface`, if your source and destination are still valid you shouldn't free them. Are you sure you're not creating new objects and for example, pushing them in an array?

Comment: i found it, i was creating a new "message = TTF_RenderText_Solid( font, msg.c_str(), textColor );" over and over again in my main game loop instead of updating the old message. now the memory use remains steady. thanks for showing me where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have SDL as one of your tags, so I am assuming that this 2D game is using that library.

If that is the case, then it is very possible that the usage of one of the library features could be dynamically allocating memory.

If you are developing for Mac OS X, you can use the free tool bundled with Xcode called Instruments; this has a Template for identifying memory leaks.

If you are developing for Windows, there are a number of tools out there that you can use, one of them being Intel's Parallel Studio, which has a memory analysis tool built into it, though it is not free.

Another option, for observing memory usage, may be to use the cross platform Google C++ Testing Framework. This framework will allow you to test portions of your code, so that you may see what calls to SDL are causing your memory to grow quickly.